# Android 9 WebView (also admob ads) not loading after Chrome update

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, chromium, android-9.0-pie

We have an application that depends heavily on web views 
we noticed after last week that if an android 9 user spent some time loading webviews about 10 to 30 after that webviews just show blank page and loading progress gets stock at 10%

Also admobe native ads stop showing

the only thing changed was chrome update to 77.0.3865.73
we tested on android 9 that has not updated to that version everything works perfectly ( chrome 74.0.3729.136)

when debugging the only message I get is :

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
```

but this message start showing from the first ever WebView created
and when the WebViews start showing blank that error stop showing .

I saw this [article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/09/11/chrome-bug-is-causing-web-pages-inside-apps-to-freeze-and-crash/) saying there is a problem with the new version too

**UPDATE :**
Follow this [thread](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1005077) to check if bug was resolved :

**UPDATE [30/1/2010]:**

The issue is back , please follow and up vote [this ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1044432)

Comment: I also have a problem with the web view not working in the app.
The cause is unknown, but it has been since the chrome 77 update.

Comment: The chrome 77.0.3865.92 has just been released.
It is not known if this version has fixed the problem.

Comment: @HJByun issue still present in 77.0.3865.92

Comment: happens to me as well since upgraded to chrome 77

Comment: Please see this link for this issue. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1005077

Comment: @HJByun thank you, I'll update the question to follow that thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bug in chrome [thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1005077) an now fixed on version 77.0.3865.116

Comment: I´m using Android 7.0 and 7.1 and I´m still getting the same message... "WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw".

Comment: @Jorgesys yes i'm facing the issue again for chrom version: 78.0.3904.108 , i updated the ticket and chrom team asked me to open another bug thread, i'll try over the weekend , this bug is so frustrating  :(

Comment: Problem remains in version Chrome/79.0.3945.116. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Dutch77 unfortunately no , please use [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1005077) to revive it or create a new one and share it here please